# Grouping Pandas Dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following dataset :
[image]

I want to group the data based on userid,deviceid and ticketid. TicketStartTime should be the earliest entry for that Ticketid. TicketEndTime should be the latest entry for that TicketID. TicketStatus should be the one corresponding to the latest  TicketEndTime .

Desired Dataset :
[image]

Comment: Could you show your efforts SO is not a code writing service, also can you post raw data, code to reproduce your df also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `agg` method on the groupby object to select aggregations per column:

```py
df.groupby(['UserID', 'DeviceID', 'TicketID']).agg({
    'TicketStatus': 'last',
    'TicketStartTime': 'first',
    'TicketEndTime': 'last'
}).reset_index()
```